# Variable Not In Scope for Lambda

Tags: c++, lambda, clock

I'm trying to diagnose a timing issue on a multi-core processor [Xeon Silver].  I think that the clocks have not been configured or synced between the processor.  I'm using Eli Bendersky's [credited in the code snippet] threading examples to build a test instrument.  I have made three changes.  I made made the sleep occur first, and I added a call to std::chrono::system_clock::now() and tried to print it out.  I'm building with gcc 4.8.5 on CentOS 7.5.

The code is as follows:

```
// // Eli Bendersky [http://eli.thegreenplace.net]
// This code is in the public domain.
#include <algorithm>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <pthread.h>

int main(int argc, const char** argv) {
  unsigned num_cpus = std::thread::hardware_concurrency();
  std::cout << "Launching " << num_cpus << " threads\n";

  // A mutex ensures orderly access to std::cout from multiple threads.
  std::mutex iomutex;
  std::vector<std::thread> threads(num_cpus);
  for (unsigned i = 0; i < num_cpus; ++i)
  {
    threads[i] = std::thread([&iomutex, i]
    {
       // Simulate important work done by the tread by sleeping for a bit...
      std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(200));
      {
         std::chrono::time_point ti = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
         // Use a lexical scope and lock_guard to safely lock the mutex only for
         // the duration of std::cout usage.
         std::lock_guard<std::mutex> iolock(iomutex);
         std::cout << "Thread #" << i << " hit its clock at: " << ti.time_since_epoch() << "\n";
       }
    });
  }

  for (auto& t : threads) {
      t.join();
  }
  return 0;
}
```

I build with make:

```
CXX = g++
CXXFLAGS = -std=c++11 -Wall -O3 -g -DNDEBUG -pthread
LDFLAGS = -lpthread -pthread

clock-check: clock-check.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $^ -o $@ $(LDFLAGS)
```

GCC gives me the following error:

```
[user@sbc1 concur]$ make clock-check
g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -O3 -g -DNDEBUG -pthread clock-check.cpp -o clock-check -lpthread -pthread
clock-check.cpp: In lambda function:
clock-check.cpp:32:67: error: ‘ti’ was not declared in this scope
      std::cout << "Thread #" << i << " hit its clock at: " << ti.time_since_epoch() << "\n";
                                                               ^
make: *** [clock-check] Error 1
```

ti is clearly in the same block scope as the print statement, and I'm baffled why the compiler is complaining.  I have not found any restrictions on variables local to the lambda.  Most of what I have found has been references to captures.

Comment: is this the complete error message? Here gcc complains about the declaration of `ti` already, which also explains the other error: https://godbolt.org/z/jMTu_b

Comment: @idclev463035818 That is the totality of the error message that I got, cut and pasted into my post.  I am using GCC 4.8.5 which I know is not fully C++11 compliant. I figured I would get standards errors if that were a problem.

Comment: If I change the type to auto, the print statement chokes later:

    clock-check.cpp:32:39: error: cannot bind ‘std::basic_ostream<char>’ lvalue to ‘std::basic_ostream<char>&&’
          std::cout << "Thread #" << i << " hit its clock at: " << ti.time_since_epoch() << "\n"; [not the whole error in this case, follow up with template arguments complaints]

Comment: with c++17 (CTAD), you would go to next error, about printing `time_since_epoch`.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem lies in this line:

```
std::chrono::time_point ti = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
```

`std::chrono::time_point` expect a type argument (e.g. `std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock>`)

Prefer to use `auto` in this case:

```
auto ti = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
```

Then, you'll have an error since you try to output a `std::chrono::duration` in an output stream.

You should do:

```
std::cout << "Thread #" << i << " hit its clock at: " << ti.time_since_epoch().count() << "\n";
```

Comment: I tried auto for the type first.  It lead to this complaint: clock-check.cpp:32:39: error: cannot bind ‘std::basic_ostream<char>’ lvalue to ‘std::basic_ostream<char>&&’
          std::cout << "Thread #" << i << " hit its clock at: " << ti.time_since_epoch() << "\n"; [plus more compiler cruft that is typical when things like this happen]

Comment: *"Your problem lies in this line:"* or this one `CXXFLAGS = -std=c++11` :-) C++17 has CTAD.

Comment: @David, I explained how to fix your new error at the end of my answer ;)

Comment: @Jarod42 indeed, I don"t know if C++11 is a requirement of the OP so I kept it :)

Comment: Whoops!  Thanks @NicolasDusart  That line was literally tl;dr .

Comment: std::chrono is a C++11 thing.  I'm trying to skin the cat with the tools that I have.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a bug in older gcc versions. With gcc 10.1 (--std=c++11) I get the [error](https://godbolt.org/z/n9L-CK):

```
<source>: In lambda function:   
<source>:23:34: error: missing template arguments before 'ti'    
   23 |          std::chrono::time_point ti = std::chrono::system_clock::now();    
      |                                  ^~    
<source>:27:67: error: 'ti' was not declared in this scope; did you mean 'i'?    
   27 |          std::cout << "Thread #" << i << " hit its clock at: " << ti.time_since_epoch() << "\n";    
      |                                                                   ^~    
      |
```

The error about the missing template parameter (which is missing with gcc 4.5.8) on the declaration explains the second error.

Strangely gcc 4.8.5 with -std=c++11 happily compiles the code if you remove the line with `std::cout`: https://godbolt.org/z/6LREHF

Comment: default might be C++14.

Answer (score 0):

Class template deduction is not available until c++17, so you need to specify your template parameters for `chrono::timepoint`. Alternatively, use auto:

```
 auto ti = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
```

Furthermore, you attempt to stream a `chrono::duration` type, which is not possible. Use `ti.time_since_epoch().count()`.

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f2b711bab137ceea)